# Best move in algebraic notation

Tags: positional-play, puzzles

I have no experience in chess, and I tried my best to answer this question myself but am finding difficulties. What is the answer? It's for another game.

[image]

Comment: 0

Can you describe what you think the best move is, in any format. Looks like this might be the password game but not sure. Also not sure it's good practice to offer advise on on-going games if this is a proper game,

Answer (score 1):

**1. Nxf8?! Qxg4+ 2. Kh1 Qe4+** is winning for White. But **1. Qxf8+ Bxf8 2. Rxf8#** is undeniably better.

```
[Title "White to Move"]
[FEN "5rk1/1p1q2bp/p2pN1p1/2pP2Bn/2P3P1/1P6/P4QKP/5R2 w - - 0 1"]

1. Qxf8+ Bxf8 2. Rxf8# (1. Nxf8?! Qxg4+ 2. Kh1 Qe4+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nxf8 wins material and probably the best. Potential attacks on the king though.

Comment: There is a better one.

Comment: **1. Nxf8?! Qxg4+ 2. Kh1 Qe4+** is winning for White.  But **1. Qxf8+ Bxf8 2. Rxf8#** is undeniably better.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! I am only 1200 fide so my tactics need work